# Splitting a white-spaced string using sscanf()

Tags: c++, scanf, split

I'm trying to split a long string with white-spaces, using `sscanf()`.

For example: I need to split this

```
We're a happy family
```

into

```
We're
a
happy
family
```

I tried the following approach

```
char X[10000];
fgets(X, sizeof(X) - 1, stdin); // Reads the long string
if(X[strlen(X) - 1] == '\n') X[strlen(X) - 1] = '\0'; // Remove trailing newline
char token[1000];
while(sscanf(X, "%s", token) != EOF) {
    printf("%s | %s\n", token, X);
}
```

The previous code goes into an infinite loop outputting `We're | We're a happy family`

I tried to replace `sscanf()` with C++ `istringstream`, it worked fine.

What makes X keep it's value? Shouldn't it be removed from buffer like normal stream?

Comment: try strtok instead.  note, though, that it is not re-entrant.

Comment: Why would you ask for sscanf and tag it with c++ only ? Trust me, there are c experts who have such snippets at the top of their head, and many c++ guys do not bother when `istringstream` works.

Comment: See another option here [How do I tokenize a string in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/53849/how-do-i-tokenize-a-string-in-c)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sscanf()` does store information about the buffer it previously read from and will always start from the address (buffer) passed to it. A possible solution would be to the use `%n` format specifier to record the position the last `sscanf()` stopped at and pass `X + pos` as the first argument to `sscanf()`. For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    const char* X = "hello again there";
    char token[1000];
    int current_pos = 0;
    int pos = 0;
    while (1 == sscanf(X + current_pos, "%999s%n", token, &pos))
    {
        current_pos += pos;
        printf("%s | %s\n", token, X + current_pos);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

See demo at http://ideone.com/XBDTWm .

Or just use `istringstream` and `std::string`:

```
std::istringstream in("hello there again");
std::string token;
while (in >> token) std::cout << token << '\n';
```

Comment: That did exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot for the help, and the info about sscanf!!